# Laravel Post with Postman

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, postman

I'm building on Laravel 5.4 and trying to make a post request with postman, I have added the csrf token and just passing something as id.
I'm still getting `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)`

So here's my Postman:
[image]

- I tried both `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and `_token` as headers.
- I tried to put them as form-data and x-www-form.

nothing is working right for me in postman, yet in laravel my view and ajax are launching all good, **but I need to work with postman on this.**

Someone mentioned **Postman Interceptor** but after downloading it and turning it on both postman and browser... and well, nothing really happens, other than watching all the XHR that goes through my browser to include my request. Any leads on this? :)

Comment: did you try `_token` as part of form data? it should work

Comment: Check the `headers` tab of postman and check if there is a `X-CSRF-TOKEN ` field in there

Comment: The token you use seems to be really short, are you sure you are sending correct token? If you can not help it just disable the csrf middleware and continue to work... (enable it on live server tho).

Answer (score 0):

always you can stop csrf for some route like admin you can do this throw open middleware and VerifyCsrfToken

And write any route in

```
protected $except = [
    'admin/*'
];
```

OR
You can remove \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, from array $middlewareGroups in App\Http\Kernel class.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using token you can try setting the token in the auth tab with bearer token and the other parameters like "id" on body tab

[image: post in postman with token auth]